# Why shows NAN? Trying to use a result to calculate other

Tags: javascript, html

I dont understand why cannot show "demo2" result:

```js
function test() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("myId").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userInput * 120;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = demo * 1, 21 + " €";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-]/g,'');" id="myId"/> Trucks No<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
<!-- RESULT1 -->
<p id="demo"></p>
<!-- RESULT2 -->
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: Where is the ``demo`` variable?

Comment: `userInput` is a string. You need to convert it to a number like `var userInput = Number(document.getElementById("myId").value);` or something.

Comment: @Andy: The `*` operator will do the conversion implicitly.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Rejith has helpfully formatted it correctly for you (as I was in the process of doing, but he/she got there first).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, true, but I find it's good to get in the habit of explicitly telling the code (particularly if you're just starting out with JS) what to do because sometimes you might get a  situation like `'121' + 4`and it doesn't do what you think it should because it _doesn't_ do the conversion. My comment could have been better worded. :)

Comment: @Andy: Yeah, I always parse explicitly too. :-)

Comment: The third line in the function says that the content of `demo2` should be `demo * 1` and then there’s a no-op expression of `21 + " €"`. This should’ve probably been `* 1.21 + "€"`. `demo` is still not a number, it’s an `HTMLParagraphElement`.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems:

1. JavaScript's numeric literals use `.`, not `,`, as the decimal point:

   ```
   document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = demo * 1.21 + " €";
   // Changed to . -------------------------------------^
   ```

   (You didn't get a syntax error because JavaScript has a comma operator.)
2. You've ended your `input` **before** the `oninput` attribute.
3. You've used `demo` without assigning it a value explicitly, so you're relying on the automatic global created for the element by the browser (because it has `id="demo"`). **Strongly** recommend not relying on those, the global namespace is far too crowded. Do what you did in the first calculation: Use `getElementById`. Probably best to just find it once and use a variable for it.
4. You've used the element (`demo`) as though it were a number. It isn't. You'd need to get its text (`innerHTML`)

So with just those changes, it works:

```js
function test(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("myId").value;
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    demo.innerHTML = userInput * 120;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = demo.innerHTML * 1.21 + " €";
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" id="myId"/> 
Trucks No<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>

<!-- RESULT1 --> <p id="demo"></p>   
<!-- RESULT2 --> <p id="demo2"></p>
```

***But***, I would go further:

1. Parse the numbers on purpose, allowing for the fact that different ways of parsing do different things. `parseInt` lets you ensure that the numbers are parsed with the right number base, but also stops on the first invalid character, so `parseInt("123abc", 10)` is `123` rather than `NaN`. `Number()` doesn't have that problem, but guesses the number base from the string, and treats `""` as `0`. So you'll want to handle things in whatever way seems reasonable to you.
2. Don't use the **string** result you've put in `demo` as the input to the second calcuation. Instead, remember the numeric result and use that.
3. Don't use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Instead, use modern event handling, not least so that your functions don't have to be globals.